# vb.net addin outlook positem

Tags: vb.net, outlook, add-in

I am working with vb.net addin outlook 2010. I have an exchange server 2003. We have a public folder that is used to store client emails. Our system send emails to clients and when they reply, it is saved in a public as a postItem not mailItem. I do not know how that happen.
I need to convert that postItem into mailItem because I want to start a workflow with that message.

I am able to get most of the field from PostItem, but I am not able to get CC and TO. I do not know what property from PostItem keep that information.

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually copying data? HAve you tried to just reset the MessageClass property from IPM.Post to IPM.Note?

Comment: In an answer you should not ask questions. You should **answer** them.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did. The "?" above means a suggestion to do something the OP apparently has not done. I am also guilty of not properly capitalizing the word "have".

Comment: Hi Dimitry, I am reading the item into an object class. When I convert that item into PostItem I do not have any problem because that item is a Post, but when I convert to MailItem I got errors. I am trying to read emails that come from our clients. I do not know why our Exchange 2003 changes client messages into PostItems. Now I have to convert PostItem into MailItem to start reading fields such as CC and To. Thanks for your help

Comment: Reset the PostItem.MessageClass property to IPM.Note, save the item, store its entry id in a variable. Release the original PostItem object (set it to Nothing in VB or call Marshal.ReleaseComObject in .Net), reopen it using Namespace.GetItemFromID. You will now have a MailItem object.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook PostItem does not have CC or BCC properties.
I just look at the MSDN reference and I don't see TO field either. 
Here is the PostItem documentation: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865387.aspx

Without seeing your code, I have no idea why your received email saves as PostItem. 
Can you post the routine that saves to the public Exchange folder?

Comment: Hello, I was talking with network administrator about this issue, and he told me that Exchange server 2003 convert an email into postItem when it is saved into a public folder. I am trying to read postitem properties and create a mailitem to start using in a workflow. I created a userForm using outlook form designer, and I created a form base on post item. When I open any post message. I am able to see CC and To but I can not get its values. Thanks for any help.